# Can't install lxml with 32-bit python 2.7, on CentOS

Tags: python, lxml

I'm developing with Python on CentOS. Needed Python 2.7 for a certain project. Didn't want to mess with the existing Python 2.6 (64-bit) installation, so installed Python 2.7 (32-bit). Haven't had a problem up until now.

Now I need a new library: lxml. It's actually already installed in the default 2.6 installation, but I need it for Python 2.7. None of the existing installation instruction seem to work. Specifically, I can't use a package manager (for CentOS it's yum), because it is only updating things for the default 2.6 installation. And again, everything from yum is already complete because Python 2.6 already has lxml installed.

If I type in "pip install lxml" I get a ton of error messages but finally it says, "Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?"

Okay, fine. So if I type in "STATIC_DEPS=true pip install lxml", it just times out and fails to download the prerequisites.

Any solution, especially sticking just to pip?

Comment: Sooooo.... Did you install libxml2 and all its buddies installed then?

Comment: What am I supposed to install? Trying to install "libxml2-python" just gives me "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement libxml2-python".

Comment: Libxml2 is a Linux library, not a python module. `sudo apt-get install libxml2` will do.

Comment: It's already installed. As I said, the existing lxml library in the Python 2.6 installation works perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you give it a try? Maybe they didn't install libxml2 on the entire system.

Comment: Also, you will need libxml2-utils on some systems (aka libxml's buddies)

Comment: Correction to my above comment -- I couldn't use pip, but I did verify that "libxml2-python" is already installed through yum, as is its "devel" counterpart. And yes, I tried to install "libxml2" again. This might be a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem, since I don't see a version of "libxml2-python" that has a "i686" extension, as "libxml2" does.

Comment: libxml2-utils does not exist on yum.

Comment: Did you also get libxslt?

Comment: Yes, and I even made sure I had the 32 and 64 bit versions of it.